# At the time of priniting page is breaking in 2 page but first page has blank space

Tags: html, css, printing

I had created a bill format in HTML and when I am viewing it in browser it viewed perfectly but when I am trying to print it is breaking in 2 pages. I am attaching my html code here for reference:-

```
I had uploaded code on jsfiddle and here is the link of the code
 

    https://jsfiddle.net/rohitarya/oyucgz4k/1/
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your table doesn't fit on A4 format. Try to make less paddings and make a font smaller. It could help you.

To add line breaker you could make CSS class for example linebreaker or any you would like:

```
@media print {
    .linebreak { page-break-before: always; }
}
```

Then just add an empty DIV with this class where you need to make a line break:

```
<div class="linebreak"> </div>
```

Comment: Problem is item table is going to next page not brpinting on first page in blank space.

Comment: In this case maybe it is better to put linebraker manually

Comment: but items are printing dynamically. I don't know how many items are in the table to make linebraker

Comment: Then maybe it is good idea to add linebreaker before items

Comment: Can you please share code snippet what to do

Comment: Made the changes to answer

Comment: @RohitAshokArya Does it help somehow?

Comment: No it didn't help

Comment: Got answer it is causing problem because of line break adjusted line break css property and it is working now. Thanks